# When is the product of Dirac delta distributions defined?

Tags: dirac-delta, product-measure

Wikipedia defines a [$n$-dimensional delta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Generalizations) as just taking

$$\delta (\mathbf{x}) = \prod_{j=1}^n \delta (x_j)$$

but also cautions

> However, despite widespread use in engineering contexts, [it] should be manipulated with care, since the product of distributions can only be defined under quite narrow circumstances.

Wikipedia cites a couple of books, neither of which do I have access to. I am having difficulty imagining what these narrow circumstances would be, and I would like to understand what they are before I tackle a problem that requires this product measure.

Under what (narrow) circumstances is the product measure defined?

Comment: There is no problem in defining tensor tensor product of Distributions, which is the case here ...

Comment: They are very narrow :-) The problem is that distributions are elements of the dual of an algebra, so their natural multiplicative structure is that of a *coalgebra*.

Comment: With $n=2$ the *tensor product of two distributions $\in D(\Bbb{R})$* just means that $T(x)S(y)$ is the distribution $\in D(\Bbb{R}^2)$ defined by $\langle T(x)S(y),\varphi \rangle = \langle S(y),\langle T,\varphi(.,y) \rangle$